How to correctly setup getElementById?
I am having trouble with getElementById() not working and I am unsure what is wrong.
My HTML body:
<button type="button" id="up">Increase Volume</button>
<button type="button" id="down">Decrease Volume</button>
<script src="final.js"></script>

My script file:
const upButton = document.getElementById("up");
const downButton = document.getElementById("up");


initialize();

function initialize(){

    upButton.setAttribute("width", "300px");
    console.log(upButton.getAttribute("width"));
    upButton.setAttribute("left", (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)).toString() + "px");

    downButton.setAttribute("top", (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)).toString() + "px");
    downButton.setAttribute("left", (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)).toString() + "px");
}


What specifically fails here?  Can you update this to a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem?

there seems to be a typo here const downButton = document.getElementById("up"); ???

None of the positioning commands work and right after I attempt to set the width I print the width but it always comes out as null

those attributes are not valid, you should modify the style instead

upButton.style.setProperty("width", ...)

@HarryPotter: Works for me.  As for "the positioning commands" it's not clear what specifically you're expecting.  You're setting essentially custom attributes.  Did you mean to set CSS styles instead?  (As an aside... You may find it easier to write and maintain if you define CSS classes for your styling and toggle those classes on the elements.)

You're using setAttribute with expectations of a different operation.
When you do upButton.setAttribute("width", "300px"); you're essentially doing the following:
<button type="button" class="button" id="up" width="300px" left="359px" style="width: 300px;">Increase Volume</button>
This is visible if you click 'inspect element' on the button. This would work if the button actually utilizes such attributes.
See docs: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp
Now to actually achieve what you want, as another comment suggested, you should target the style object:


const upButton = document.getElementById("up");
const downButton = document.getElementById("down");

function initialize(){
  upButton.style.width = '300px'
  upButton.style.left = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)).toString() + "px"

  downButton.style.top = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)).toString() + "px"
  downButton.style.left = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)).toString() + "px"
}

initialize();
.button {
  position: absolute;
}
<button type="button" onclick="initialize()">Change position</button>

<button type="button" class="button" id="up">Increase Volume</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="down">Decrease Volume</button>



